# How to save PDF files in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, frontend, pdf, magento-2.2.5

I have a frontend form which consists of two fields. One is a PDF file uploader field. The second one is a ZIP file uploader field.

Now how do I save these two fields in the database? In which directory do I need to save the PDF files and ZIP files?

Answer (score 0):

See my Controller for upload pdf.

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor>\<ModuleName>\Controller\Adminhtml\brochures;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
/**
 * Description of Upload
 *
 * @author dharmendra
 */
class Upload extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
    protected $_directory_list;
    protected $_filesystem;
    protected $_storeManager; 

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
        $this->_directory_list = $directory_list;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_filesystem = $filesystem;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry);
    }

    public function execute(){
        $success = false;
        $extError = true;
        $responseArray = array();

        $filenameArray = isset($_FILES['imagename']['name']) ? $_FILES['imagename']['name'] : array();
        $filename = "";
        foreach ($filenameArray as $index => $value) {
            $ext = pathinfo($value['file'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $filename = $value['file'];
        }

        if(in_array(strtolower($ext), ['pdf', 'doc', 'docx'])) {

            if($filename != ''){
                $path = $this->_filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath('productpdf');

                $renamedFileName = strtotime('now').'_'.str_replace(' ','_',$filename);
                $targetFile = $path.'/'. $renamedFileName;

                $tmpnameArray = isset($_FILES['imagename']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['imagename']['tmp_name'] : array();
                $tempname = "";

                foreach ($tmpnameArray as $index => $value) {
                    $tempname = $value['file'];
                }

                if($tempname != ''){

                    if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $targetFile)) {
                        $success = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $extError = false;
            $message = __('Please upload only PDF, DOC, DOCX.');
        }

if($success){

            $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);    
            $data['imagename'] = $renamedFileName;
        }
$model->setData($data);

        try {
            $model->save();

            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The Brochures has been saved.'));
            $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Backend\Model\Session')->setFormData(false);
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $model->getId(), '_current' => true]);
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();die;
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the Brochures.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Still you facing any issue let me know.