# Magento 2 How add PDF Uploader to UI Component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, pdf, image-upload, pdf-uploads

How do I add a PDF uploader to the ui component? I could find how to add an image uploader, but I can't find how to do it for pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you

[How to save PDF files in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242544/how-to-save-pdf-files-in-magento-2)

If not please share code, we will solve it.